# POWERSHELL - Variable in Get-service -Name $Var

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

Here my script :

## Relance de Service sur machine distante

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force
$passwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force -String PASSWORD #Remplacer 'Password' par votre Mot de passe Datacenter
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "LOGIN",$passwd #Remplacer 'login' par votre login datacenter
$Server = Read-Host -Prompt 'Veuillez entrer le nom du serveur'
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Server -Credential $cred
$Service = Read-Host -Prompt 'Veuillez entrer le nom du service'
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {$A = get-service -Name $Service}
if ($A.Status -eq "Stopped") {$A.start()}
elseIf ($A.status -eq "Running") {Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow $A.name "is running"}
Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
```

My script is almost working, but i've got an 'error' or i missed something.
When i use prompt to get the server name $Server and put it in the variable everything is ok.
But when i use prompt to get the Service name in a variable $Service, and use get-service -name $Service, it doesn't work.
Why?
Could you help me please?

Comment: `Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {param($Service) $A = get-service -Name $Service} -ArgumentList $Service` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is not with `Get-Service` but with `Invoke-Command`. The variable `$Service` you use is not passed from your session to the invoked command. There are multiple options to do this:

By param (as [Paxz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6404133/paxz) mentioned in comments):

```
-ScriptBlock {param($Service) $A = get-service -Name $Service} -ArgumentList $Service
```

By `using:`:

```
-ScriptBlock {$A = get-service -Name $using:Service}
```

By argument directly:

```
-ScriptBlock {$A = get-service -Name $args[0]} -ArgumentList $Service
```

Also keep in mind the scope of variables while trying to restart them.

---

Some useful links to check when it comes to passing variables to remote sessions:

- [PowerShell: Passing variables to remote commands](https://kevinmarquette.github.io/2016-08-28-PowerShell-variables-to-remote-commands/)
- [How to pass arguments for remote commands](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2009/12/29/how-to-pass-arguments-for-remote-commands/)

Comment: I'm new here, so i don't know how to do that.

Comment: I did it. Thanks